# How to sort a PHP array based on a second array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two simple arrays. One is an array of posts ($posts) and the other is an array of post ID's that should be on top of the stream, like they are featured ($featured). I am trying to find an efficient way to loop through them and if an ID is in both arrays, move it to the beginning of the $posts array, and the ones that are moved should be sorted ASC by $featured['order'], so for example, some posts ($posts):

```
Array
(
    [ab77] => Status_Update Object
        (
            [id] => ab77
            [title] => Status Update
         )

    [b4k7] => Status_Update Object
         (
             [id] => b4k7
             [title] => Status Update
         )
    [4d55] => Status_Update Object
         (
             [id] => 4d55
             [title] => Status Update
         )

    [13c5] => Status_Update Object
         (
             [id] => 13c5
             [title] => Status Update
          )

     [3aa2] => Status_Update Object
          (
              [id] => 3aa2
              [title] => Status Update
           )
)
```

and then some posts which should be featured ($featured):

```
Array
(
    [13c5] => Array
         (
             [id] => 13c5
             [order] => 1
         )

    [3a71] => Array
         (
             [id] => 3a71
             [order] => 2
         )

    [4d55] => Array
         (
             [id] => 4d55
             [order] => 3
         )

)
```

So the $posts array should end up sorted like this:

13c5
4d55
ab77
bk47
3aa2

How do I do this without a bunch of slow loops?

Comment: It looks like you've got the ID as the array keys already, so you won't need nested loops - just one and inside you can check `array_key_exists('13c5', $featured))` etc

Comment: If possible I would build the arrays out correctly in the first place. This will most likely be faster and elegant. It sounds like you want to create a new array of data from two existing queries. My suggestion is make a new query that give you the data you want instead of manipulating the existing data. This may not be best for your situation but in many cases it is.

Comment: Use `uksort` to sort using a user-written comparison function. The function should check whether both keys are in the featured array using `array_key_exists`. If they're both in or both not in, compare them with `<`.

Comment: how do i do that and then also sort the ones that get moved, by their order key?

Comment: DutGRIFF unfortunately, the arrays are coming from to separate databases entirely, so i cannot join.

Comment: You can use backticks (to the left of the 1 on the keyboard) to make `inline` code.

Answer (score 3):

This should be doable with [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) and [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
uksort( $posts, function ( $a, $b ) use ( $featured ) {
    $fa = ( isset( $featured[$a] ) ? $featured[$a]['order'] : INF );
    $fb = ( isset( $featured[$b] ) ? $featured[$b]['order'] : INF );
    if ( $fa != $fb ) return ( $fa < $fb ? -1 : +1 );
    // could add a tie-breaker comparison here
    return 0;
} );
```

Comment: That almost works, it returns the not-featured posts on top with the featured ones on the bottom but sorted correctly, like this:  `ab77 bk47 3aa2 13c5 4d55`

Comment: I'm trying to get to `13c5 4d55 ab77 bk47 3aa2`

Comment: Strange. Can you show the exact code you're using? And maybe use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` to display the arrays, so that there's no ambiguity about types?

Answer (score 0):

This is the messy answer I came up with works.

```
$found, $not_found = array();

foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $featured)) {
        $found[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $not_found[$key] = $value;
    }
}

usort($found, 'sort_by_order');

function sort_by_order ($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
}

$new = array_merge($found, $not_found);
```